# AttributeError: 'ADC' object has no attribute 'atten'

Tags: python

I have a little problem whit pyboard. I want to measure voltage and I want to use this program:

```py
from machine import Pin, ADC

adc=ADC(Pin('A0'))
adc.atten(ADC.ATTN_11DB)
3.3/4095
adc.read()* 0.000805
```

but I have problem with attribute `atten` and read
[image]

Comment: please edit this post to meet the [ minimal reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the ADC has no method named ADC.atten() to call. You can see [here](https://docs.pycom.io/firmwareapi/pycom/machine/adc/) all it's methods.

Comment: It does, according to MicroPython. https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/esp32/quickref.html#adc-analog-to-digital-conversion